# .Net Windows Service to monitor mailbox

Tags: .net, windows-services, email

I need to create a .Net windows service to monitor a mailbox and process attachments (if found) on the emails and then delete the email from the server.

I have two questions I'd like your thoughts on:

1. POP3 or IMAP to connect to the mail server?
2. Which POP3/IMAP library should I use. At this stage we're just doing a proof of concept, so a free one would be my preference.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after doing some more research I've gone with C#Mail (http://csharpmail.codeplex.com/). So far it seems to do the job pretty well.

EDIT: Ended up having some random problems with c#mail so we ended up purchasing Rebex Mail and it has worked wonderfully well.

Comment: Adding clickable links: http://csharpmail.codeplex.com/ and http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/

Answer (score 0):

1. What does the server support? You will want to support both in many cases. In general, IMAP is superior in functionality, and superior in containing many funny edge cases, especially with less than stellar servers.

Comment: I believe the server is running MailEnable so IMAP and POP3 are supported. I'm not sure why I'd want to support both IMAP and POP3 though? I was just wondering if there were any benefits in using one over the other

Comment: @Brent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol#Advantages_over_POP

Comment: Thanks for that. None of the pros or cons there have much bearing on my application, given how simple it is, so I guess I'll just go with the best library I can find and use whatever it uses.